# How to switch PHP version back and forth?

Tags: php, version, switching

I installed LAMP manually on Ubuntu, let's say my current version of PHP is 5.2 and I want to switch to PHP 5.3 for awhile, is that possible? No xampp solution please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most hassle free way would be to run it as CGI instead of using mod_apache. Then you can run both simultaneously by simply changing handler `.php` with a .htaccess or in a vhost.

Comment: How can I do that? Also I already have my lamp running, only need to do is to have another php version and make switch between them at a time.

Comment: http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/php-cgi/debian-5-lenny#configure_apache_for_php_cgi Then install you other version of php in `/opt` or what have you. Then you add the necessary configs to the individual virtual hosts or set them up on the main host but using different file extensions - you default them to two seperate extensions and if you want a particular folder to run the default in a differnt version youd use an AddHandler in a .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

You can install them in something like `/opt/php5.2` and `/opt/php5.3` and then use `update-alternatives` to switch between the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
for 5.2

<Directory "/var/www/">
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php 
</Directory>

for 5.3

<Directory "/var/www/">
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php 
</Directory>

for 5.4
<Directory "/var/www/">
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution with .htaccess

1: Create new file 
2: name with .htaccess
3: save to your root folder

To switch to PHP 4.4:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.0:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.1:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php51 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.2:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.3:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

To switch to PHP 5.4:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```